# Mono Assembly Redirects (Running under Node with EdgeJS) Razor?

Tags: .net, node.js, mono, ubuntu-12.04

I can't seem to get assembly redirects to work with Mono on Ubuntu.

The Mono runtime is running under Node using EdgeJS, but I've gotten this to work on windows.

Here's one messages:

```
Assuming assembly reference `Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, publicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
matches assembly `Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. 
You may need to supply runtime policy
```

I have added the following file, which lives in the same directory as the node executable (`node` on Ubuntu):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="6.0.2.16931"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

But it doesn't make a difference.  Am I naming the config file wrong, putting it in the wrong place, something else?

*UPDATE*
It's possible the error is being generated from within the RazorEngine and I know there have been issues with RE not reading app.config...